# Execute permissions for all users not working as expected

Tags: bash, permissions

I have two bash scripts within `/usr/local/bin` and here are the permissions:

```
-rwxrwx--x 1 root root 33 Dec 30 12:18 hello.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34 Dec 30 12:28 test.sh
```

Both scripts have the same contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello $USER!"
```

I am currently a user who does not have `root` privileges.

I would expect the following:

- I cannot read **hello.sh**, but I can execute it via `bash hello.sh`
- I can read **test.sh**. but I cannot execute it via `bash test.sh`

Reading both files works as expected, but execution of both files works opposite of my expectation:

- I cannot execute **hello.sh** (even though I have execution privileges set for all users)
- I can execute **test.sh** (even though I only have read privileges set for all users).

I am missing something here. What basic concept am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/can-a-script-be-executable-but-not-readable

Ultimately, it appears that `bash` (the interpreter) is what is actually being executed.  The interpreter needs read permissions on the file/script in order to execute the file/script.

So the answer: as long as you have execute permission on your interpreter (in this case `bash`) and read permissions on the file/script you *intend* to execute, then you should be good.